# Find key in std::unordered_map won't find an existing key

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to make a simple ResourceManager which uses an ordered_map to find how to import files using the extension :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class ResourceManager;
typedef void (*ImporterFn)(const std::string& path); 

// manage files and what's in the assets/ folder
class ResourceManager 
{
public:
    ResourceManager() {};
    ~ResourceManager() {};

    void addImporter(const char* extension, ImporterFn fn) {
        // avoid adding multiple importers for one extension
        if(importers.find(extension) != importers.end())
            return;
        // add importer
        std::cout << "Adding importer for " << extension << std::endl;
        importers.emplace(extension, fn);
    }

    void loadFile(const std::string& path) {
        std::size_t extDot = path.find_last_of(".");
        std::string ext = path.substr(extDot+1);

        auto it = importers.find(ext.c_str());
        if(it != importers.end()) {
            std::cout << "Importer found for " << ext.c_str() << std::endl;
            it->second(path);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "No importer found for " << ext.c_str() << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<const char*, ImporterFn> importers{};
};
```

and I made a simple program to test it and it seems it can't find the key in the map...

```cpp
int main()
{
    ResourceManager* rsx = new ResourceManager();
    rsx->addImporter("png", [](const std::string& path){
        std::cout << "Loading png image" << std::endl;
    });

    rsx->loadFile("assets/imagetest1.png");
    rsx->loadFile("assets/imagetest2.jpeg");

    return 0;
}
```

And it output (using g++ to build this example):

```
Adding importer for png
No importer found for png
No importer found for jpeg
```

So I don't know what I can do to fix this, I tried to list the key in the importers map and it seems to be there, do I need to specify a custom predicate or is the problem somewhere else ?

Comment: When you use pointers as keys, it's the actual *pointer* which is the key, not what they point to. If you want to use strings as keys use `std::string`.

Comment: Which is to say: `ext.c_str()` is a `char*` pointing to an array of characters managed by the `std::string` `ext`. `"png"`, after experiencing array to pointer decay, is a `const char*` pointing to an constant array whose lifetime is the duration of the program. Even though both arrays say `"png"`, they are different arrays and have different addresses.

Comment: Also I was imprecise and thought that `c_str` was more similar to `data` than it was and had a non-`const` overload: `ext.c_str()` is _also_ a `const char*`. It still points to a different array that (currently) has the same contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your container is using `const char*` as a key. Note that `std::unorderd_map` uses standard operator `==` for type provided as key. In case of `const char *` this equal operator compares only a pointers.

So only case where you will find item is when you use same pointer. Pointed contest doesn't meter.

Now when you were adding item pointer to string literal was used. When you  tried get an item you used buffer of `std::string` created on runtime. This two pointers will never be the same.

Note that in C++ for handling string you should use `std::string` (and/or `std::string_view` since C++17).

So simple replacing type of key in map fixes problem:

```cpp
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ImporterFn> importers{};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GrsWcqEdT

**Extra:**
C++17 has introduced `std::filesystem::path` which will make this code simpler: https://godbolt.org/z/YxMME934h